# Remove dashicons.min.css conditionally

Tags: css

Trying to remove dashicons for non-logged in users excluding specific pages and specific categories with the following:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'go_dequeue_dashicons' );
function go_dequeue_dashicons() {
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    if ( !is_page( array( 9, 10 ) ) || !in_category( array( 29, 2 ) ) ) {
        wp_deregister_style( 'dashicons' );
    }
  }
}
```

The code works if I do not use the OR condition. In other words it works if I apply a sole IF statement either for the specific pages or for the specific categories. It doesn’t work if I use both IF statements under the OR condition. Which is the correction needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'go_dequeue_dashicons' );
function go_dequeue_dashicons() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && !is_page( array( 9, 10 ) ) && !in_category( array( 29, 2 ) ) ) {
        wp_deregister_style( 'dashicons' );
    }
}
```

I basically just combined the IF statements and changed || to &&.